# Find all integers $x$ such that $\frac{2^x+1}{x^2}$ is an integer.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We need to find all integers $x>1$ such that $$\frac{2^x+1}{x^2}$$is an integer. I have pointed out that $x=3$ works. And none of the even integer will work. How do I proceed?

Comment: This is a number theory problem, so I think you should change your tags to be more likely to get help. How much number theory do you know? Enough to show that 3 is the only prime value of x that works?

Comment: if $x$ is prime, $x$ divides $2^x-2$, but this implies $x$ divides $2^x+1$, so $x$ divides $3$

Comment: A partial result: if $x$ divides $2^x+1$ (never mind $x^2$), $x$ must be a power of $3$ times a finite number of other values, $\{1,171,13203,2354697,10970073,22032887841\}$. Of these, you might be able to show directly that $x^2 \nmid 2^x+1$.

https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~chris/papers/n_divides_2to_nplus1.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203976/find-all-n1-such-that-dfrac2n1n2-is-an-integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all $n&gt;1$ such that $\dfrac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203976/find-all-n1-such-that-dfrac2n1n2-is-an-integer)