# How to solve 1990 IMO Q3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, multiplicative-order

For my lesson on order, one of the exercises my teacher gave me was Question 3 of the 1990 IMO paper:

> Find all integers $n>1$ such that $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer.

My attempt:

---

We have $$n^2|2^n+1\Rightarrow2^n+1\equiv0\pmod{n^2}\Rightarrow2^n\equiv-1\pmod{n^2}\Rightarrow2^{2n}\equiv1\pmod{n^2}$$
Either $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=1$, $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=2$, $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=d$ where $d|n$,  or $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=2d$ where $d|n$ but $2d\nmid n$.

If $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=1$, $2^1\equiv1\pmod{n^2}$, then $n^2=1\Rightarrow n=1$. This contradicts the requirements for $n$.

If $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=2$, $2^2\equiv1\pmod{n^2}$, then $n^2=1$ or $3$ so $n$ is $1$ or $\sqrt3$. This also contradicts the requirements for $n$.

If $\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=d$ then there exists an integer $k$ such that $dm=n$. Then $2^n=2^{dm}=\left(2^d\right)^m\equiv1^m=1\pmod{n^2}$. This contradicts $2^n\equiv-1$ which we showed earlier.

Therefore $$\text{ord}_{n^2}(2)=2d$$

By Euler's Theorem $2^{\phi(n^2)}\equiv1\pmod{n^2}$, so $2d|\phi(n^2)$. As $\phi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}\frac{p-1}p=nk$ where $k=\prod_{p|n}\frac{p-1}p$, and $n$ and $n^2$ share the same prime factors, we have $$\phi(n^2)=n^2\prod_{p|n}\frac{p-1}p=n\left(n\prod_{p|n}\frac{p-1}p\right)=n(nk)=n\phi(n)$$

Continuing,

$$2d|\phi(n^2)\Rightarrow2d|n\phi(n)\Rightarrow2|m\phi(n)$$

Where $dm=n$. This means either $m$ is even (which implies $n$ is even) or $\phi(n)$ is even.

---

Unfortunately, I am still far from actually solving the problem. It's clear that showing $n$ is even or $\phi(n)$ is even is not sufficient to show that $\frac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer (counterexamples include $n=4$ and $n=5$). There are infinitely many numbers satisfying the conditions I laid down. However, I'm not sure how to proceed, so I would like some assistance in finishing the question.

Comment: If $n>1$, then $2^n$ is even, so $2^n+1$ is odd, so $n^2|2^n+1$ means $n$ is odd

Comment: Did you mean if ord$_{n^2}(2)=\color{red}2, 2^2\equiv1\pmod{ n^2}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes I did, thanks for the catch

Comment: You can find the anwers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203996/798113

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all $n&gt;1$ such that $\dfrac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203976/find-all-n1-such-that-dfrac2n1n2-is-an-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$Consider the smallest prime divisor of $n$.

Then use the "lifting the exponent " lemma.

Then again consider the second smallest prime of $n$

At first consider the smallest prime divisor say $p$ of $n$.It can't be $2$.
Then, $2^{2n}=1 \pmod {p}$,but also by FLT $2^{p-1}=1 \pmod {p}$.

These two together implies that $2^{gcd(p-1,2n)}=1 \pmod {p}$.But now, $gcd(p-1,2n)=2$ since,any other prime of $n$ would be bigger than $p-1$.This implies that $3$ has to be the smallest prime of $n$ .since $2^2=1 \pmod{p}$ from above.

Now deduce using that lifting the exponent lemma that the highest power of $3$ dividing $n$ is $1$.Then, consider the smallest prime of $n/3$.

Use similar argument as above to show it has to be $7$.But from the fact that $3 \mid n$ show that that can't happen.So,the only solution would be $n=3$

(details are ommited since I wrote it to serve it as a hint)

For detailed solution .see here :[aops](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h60740p366466)

Comment: What's the lifting the exponent lemma?

Comment: https://imosuisse.ch/smo/skripte/unused/Lifting_the_exponent_EN.pdf

Comment: Okay, so what I can tell we know that $v_p(2^n+1)=v_p(2^n+1^n)=v_p(3)+v_p(n)$ for odd $n$. As $v_p(n^2)=2v_p(n)$ we need $v_p(3)\geq v_p(n)$ for all primes. As $v_p(3)=1$ for $p=3$ and $0$ otherwise, we need $v_p(n)\leq1$ for $p=3$ and $0$ otherwise. The only $n$ that satisfies the conditions is $n=3$, so we can conclude that $n=3$ is the only odd $n$. But what about for even $n$? The lemma for $v_p(2^n+1^n)$ only applies for odd $n$.

Comment: Wait I’ve realised it, $2^n+1$ is odd but $n^2$ is even. So $n$ cannot be even.

Comment: I've edited my post